# Seq24 connecting to Akai MPX8

Tags: raspberrypi, midi

I'm fairly new to Linux, SEQ24 and Midi.  Good background on Windows and programming in general.
Issue #1
I loaded seq24 (version 0.9.2) onto a Raspberry PI2.  It seemed to load OK.  However I can't make the keyboard function of SEQ24 work.  When I create a new song, and right click on the row for C2, it won't darken the portion of the row.  It just keeps the grid white.  I get no sound either.  With other apps, the sound will play through the speakers on my monitor.  Getting the keyboard of seq24 to operate properly seems to be my first issue.

Issue #2
My ultimate goal is to have seq24 on the Raspberry PI, at predefined times, request the Akai MPX8 to play a song associated with an MPX8 pad.  At other times, I have a USB-to-midi cable hooked up.  When I plug the USB end into the Raspberry PI and the Midi ends into the Akai MPX8, I get two new rows in the Output Bus selection of SEQ24:

- [1]20:0(USB2.0-MIDI MIDI 1)
- [2]20:1(USB2.0-MIDI MIDI 2)

The MPX8 only talks on channel 10, so I've selected that channel.  In order to press Pad1 on the MPX8, Note C2 (midi 036) needs to be played.  I'm trying to get SEQ24 to make a midi file that will request the Akai MPX8 to play C2 on Channel 10.  Once Issue #1 is resolved, do I need to do anything beyond selecting the proper Output Bus, channel and playing Note C2 and then saving that?

I'm using the Akai MPX8 because it has pads that someone can activate at ad-hoc times as well as via a schedule, which is where the Raspberry PI2 comes in.
Many thanks for looking at this.